# Rails console not showing fields and values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I open the rails console and print out my most recent object I am not able to see all of the fields and values. However, when I call the object.field_name it will display the value.

Does console cut off after a certain number of fields or am I experiencing some type of error?

Comment: What command did you use to print the object?

Comment: That object can have custom `export` method, for example ActiveRecord objects. May be that attribute is not an instance variable, you can see it by: `my_object.instance_variables`. May be some gem in your Gemfile override Object#inspect

Answer (score 1):

Try attributes method

```
User.first.attributes
```

Taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632742